# C# Partial Classes

Tags: c#, class, partial-classes

I currently have a solution with multiple projects that mostly use the same classes.  As a result, it appeared to me that it would be a good idea to add a class library containing these classes in the solution instead of repeating the class in each project.

However, one project I have requires a few additional properties to some of the classes that are specific to that project and will not be used anywhere else.  As a result, I thought that I should use partial classes to add these properties.  So I have done something like this:

In the class library:

```
namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public partial class Book
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string AuthorLast { get; set; }
        public string AuthorFirst { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Edition { get; set; }
        public string ISBN10 { get; set; }
        public string ISBN13 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the project (MyProject):

```
namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    public partial class Book
    {
        public string AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have referenced MyClassLibrary in MyProject (a C# windows form app), however when I try to use this class in the codebehind for the form I receive the following error:

> class MyClassLibrary.Book
>
> Warning: The type
>   'MyClassLibrary.Book' in 'C:...
>   (Project)' conflicts with the imported
>   type 'MyClassLibrary.Book' in 'C:...
>   (Class Library DLL)'.  Using the type
>   defined in 'C:...(project)'.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or if my whole approach is bad and I should be doing something else?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Partials are not for spanning assemblies. If you need to add to your class for a more specific type of usage, you should create a derived class:

```
public class MyFoo
{
    public string BasicProperty {get;set;}
}

public class MySpecificFoo : MyFoo
{
    public string AnotherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

In your project requiring the more specific type of MyFoo, utilize MySpecificFoo instead. Since it inherits/derives from MyFoo, it will have all of the properties and functionality of MyFoo, with the additional properties as well. This is part of [**Polymorphism**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28VS.80%29.aspx), which is where real power of OOP lies.

Comment: thanks! i'll try it with a derived class... still new at this!

Comment: uh...no, this is called "inheritance"!

Answer (score 10):

In short, you can't use partial classes **across projects**.  All the source must be compiled at the same time, and that's done per project.

Here's a full discussion on SO about this: [Should you use a partial class across projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309939/should-you-use-a-partial-class-across-projects)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  Do you have any ideas how I may best organize the classes then given this issue?  Should I just duplicate them in the projects or just add the property to the class in the class library even though its only for one project?
Edit: am going to try derived classes as suggested below.  thanks again

Comment: I would go with Rex's answer for a solution, inheriting the classes seems like the best approach...unless there's a reason you can't, if so, what additional restriction is there?

Comment: From [Skeet on that linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/309944/1028230): `You can't write a partial class across projects. A partial class is a compile-time-only piece of syntactic sugar - the whole type ends up in a single assembly, i.e. one project.`

Answer (score 1):

For what you're trying to do, you should instead try to use base classes and inheritance. Or even better [object composition](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html).

Comment: from the immediate description, composition is definitely not a better solution

Comment: @Steven Absolutely. I just find that it is helpful to point out because many novices learn about inheritance and then get themselves in trouble by using it **everywhere** simply because they don't know any better.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more along the lines of what you're trying to achieve.

Put all of your common classes into a class library project and compile it to a DLL.

You can then reference that DLL in external projects. Anytime you need to add a property to it for the external project you can then inherit the class and add the property there.

Answer (score 0):

all wrong.  You should consider partial methods instead.  Look 'em up.  They're exactly what you asked for.