# Partial classes in separate projects

Tags: c#, .net, module, partial-classes

I have a question the answer i cant find for.
I have solution with Module projects. There are the same class types in each. My purpose is to make them all partial and define partial method.
I tried to use the same namespace and the same Project namespace, but it doesnt work. Can somebody give me an advice how to do that?
Thanks so much.
**Upd. any workaround (in there is no straight way) will be appreciated**

Comment: Why would you like to do that in first place? because this may be XY problem?

Comment: did not understand your question.
although ill try to explain:
i have to make modularity, using CodeFirst and there has to be parial class inherited from DbContext with partial method which do its own Model configuration (adds DbSet<t> etc.) that would be programming interface, then developers just add his models, services, controllers and configures his own relations (not knowing about other modules) (in separate project of course)

Comment: You may need to explain why you need to do that, so that it will be easy to answer

Comment: just updated, see above and thanks for your interest!

Comment: and just adds partial class doing configuration in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot have a partial class span multiple projects. Partial classes are only combined within individual projects/assemblies.

See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309939/should-you-use-a-partial-class-across-projects?lq=1) for more information and some possible workarounds (e.g. inheritance and extension methods).

Comment: maybe i can somehow make the separate projects to be compiled into ONE assembly?

Comment: It is possible to combine assemblies using tools like ILMerge, but such tools are not able to combine partial classes from distinct projects.

Answer (score 2):

Partial classes are compiler magic. In other words no matter you have partial class, while compiling compiler will combine all partial classes into single unit.

Since this all happens separately for each assembly it is not possible.

Very close workaround which I can see is *Inheritance*.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work out of the box because it would mean that the same class will live in two separate assemblies (metafiles).

Workaround: you can try to merge one project into another on Pre-Build event