# Extending the properties and methods of a class across projects

Tags: c#

So what we'd like to have is a library that expands across many modules, and each add their own respective functionality. For example our base class.

```
public class Account {
  public string Username;
}
```

Then in a separate package (let's say the `ActiveDirectory` package)

```
public partial class Account {
  public UserPrincipal Principal;
}
```

which would extend our `Account` class to

```
public class Account {
  public string Username;
  public UserPrincipal Principal;
}
```

However using the `partial` keyword is only supported **within** the same project. I also don't want to just extend `Account` to an `ADAccount` because other modules will want to add their own properties and methods and there isn't a structured hierarchy of classes. Extension Methods is a possibility but they are only methods and they can't store any additional data to the class.

#### Practical Use-Case

I'd like for a user to be able to

```
Install-Package BaseLibrary
```

and get `public class Account { public string Username }` or run

```
Install-Package BaseLibrary
Install-Package BaseLibrary-ActiveDirectory
Install-Package BaseLibrary-Twitter
```

and get

```
public class Account {
  public string Username;
  public UserPrincipal Principal;
  public Twitter TwitterUser;
}
```

#### How can this be done?

Although `ExpandoObject`'s can do this I would obviously prefer a Statically Typed option.

Comment: how can this be done?

Comment: Isn't this what the Decorator pattern is for?http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/479635/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusDecoratorp

Comment: I believe the Decorator pattern implies that there is a shared interface between all of the modules. In this case the Twitter and AD modules are unrelated.

Comment: It isn't possible to add new properties to types in this way. You can only dynamically extend objects by adding [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx). The only way I can think to do this is to put the actual code files into your nuget package, rather than a DLL, and use partial classes as you suggested.

Comment: @Rhumborl I didn't know you could do that with Nuget. Would it still be possible to upgrade to a newer version of a package?

Comment: I feel like your are asking for something that is inherently not statically typed. If you get two or three different interfaces for a class depending on which plugins are installed then you have two or three different types.

Comment: @novaterata yes, I am very much bias to the Repository pattern that  javascript is able to do. Being able to do `Company.Account()` and get an object that has all of the required methods and properties for a project is very seducing.

Comment: @xori That's fine, thats what dynamic / ExpandoObject are for, but I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309939/should-you-use-a-partial-class-across-projects that might help you with other ideas.

Comment: @xori I just Googled c# Repository pattern and there seemed to be plenty of examples as well.

Comment: @novaterata yes I've been trying to understand how I should implement them