# Can T4MVC be configured to find methods defined in another assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I'm examining a scenario in which I'd be using RazorGenerator to share my MVC views between two different MVC sites, and I was wondering if it would be possible to also put partial implementations of a controller in another assembly and have T4MVC pick up on methods defined in the other assembly.

So, for instance, something like this:

**MVC Library/HomeController.cs**

```
namespace SharedNameSpace ...
public partial class HomeController
{
    public virtual ActionResult SomeSharedAction() { return View(); } 
}
```

**MVC ProjectA/HomeController.cs** - *ProjectA has reference to "MVC Library" project*

```
namespace SharedNameSpace ...
public partial class HomeController
{
    public virtual ActionResult IndexA() 
    {
        return Partial(MVC.Home.SomeSharedAction(), new { }); 
    } 
}
```

I tried looking at the `.tt` file to determine how the methods are discovered by T4MVC, but had some trouble discerning this. Here's some of the relevant code I found:

```
foreach (CodeFunction2 method in GetMethods(type))
{
    ...
    controllerInfo.ActionMethods.Add(new ActionMethodInfo(method, current));
}

static IEnumerable<CodeFunction2> GetMethods(CodeClass2 codeClass)
{
    // Only look at regular method (e.g. ignore things like contructors)
    return codeClass.Members.OfType<CodeFunction2>()
        .Where(f => f.FunctionKind == vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction);
}
```

... But I couldn't find the definition of a `CodeClass2` to determine how its `Members` is determined. (Is `CodeClass2` a generic type or something?) Is there a way this could be altered to find methods for a partial class that were defined in a referenced assembly? Not sure if T4 has access to all the features of reflection or not.

Edit: I found some more info on `CodeClass2`, apparently it's an MS type, which was unexpected due to the name. MSDN shows [latest documentation for vs2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.codeclass2_members(v=vs.90).aspx) though

Comment: I'm not sure if this person is asking for the same thing as this question, but I found this link which seems relevant https://t4mvc.codeplex.com/discussions/570079

Answer (score 0):

I realized that one of my assumptions was incorrect, and that you cannot have partial classes declared across assemblies, so the desired effect is impossible for other reasons.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/309944/526704